# How to create my own file format in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-format

Can anyone tell me how to create a document with my own format so nobody should not be read that file format.To accomplish it what i have to do? I planned to create that file using Java. Can you please tell me what are the things i have to do in that and how to do that.Or please tell me. Is there is any alternative way to do that?

Please help me!

Comment: whatever you decide to use double check what other uses your extension has. Picking one that is used by other programs can give unwanted and annoying sideeffects (example dont uses .scf because  mail software will block it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick an extension. (Possibly a mime type as well)

You need to determine what you want to write.

Finally you need to determine how you want to write it (and read it)

To be more specific, you need to provide more detail, such as, will it be text or binary?

Comment: While you are at it, also pick a mime-type.

Comment: Can you make the mime-type based on the extension you pick?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of file it is and what data it will contain.

I assume you want to use it to save data from a software you created and only readable with this software. For example, .doc are created by and read by Microsoft Word.

The first question you should ask yourself is:

> Will the file be readable by human beings?

In other words, can you open it with notepad, like a .html for example.

If yes, choose (or create) a syntax like XML, for example (which can often be the best choice).

Example:

```
<supersoft>
  <preference>
    <some-preference foo="bar" />
  </preference>
  <data>
    <some-data foo="baz" />
  </data>
</supersoft>
```

If not, simply serialize your classes with the `Serializable` interface. You can put some beacon that will tell your software it's the good kind of file, at the beginning of the file.

Example:

```
SuperSoft1101100111010110110010111010110101010101010110101011010101101010101011011010101010101010110101011010101101010101
```

The next question is:

> What extension do I want?

You can choose anything, but try to avoid already taken names. If you choose .jpg, for example, your OS will try to open the file with an image viewer. Check on the Internet if the extenson already exists.

The last question is:

> Should I be able to open my software when opening the file?

For example, double-clicking on a .xls automatically opens Excel. This step depends of the OS you are using.

I assume saving and loading data is something you already know.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an application with a GUI, note that [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can register an apps. interest in a file/content type.  See the [file service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for example and code.

> ..the launch file prompts the user to associate file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`.  ..